# GUI login failure after deleting ecryptfs

Tags: login, ecryptfs

Ubuntu 12.04: I run my OS on a 64 GB SSD.  So, space is important.  Thus, I too hastily deleted ".ecryptfs" to save 10GB.  (Ecryptfs was not set up to encrypt my home folder or the disk itself; so I do not know why it was steadily building up. I did not use it at all.)

All seemed fine but when I next booted the system, my password was not accepted at my GUI login.  I can log in from a command line, but cannot get to the GUI.  Startx does not work.  The files ".Xauthority" and ".XauthorityBak" are gone.  I can log in as the other user on the system but cannot get to my own files or access my files on my backup HDs (4 TB in total) due to permission problems.

Is there a way for me to restore my GUI login or must I re-install the system?".Xauthority"

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to recover (or at least get access to) your files again, try `ecryptfs-recover-private` it should search for encrypted private folders and try to let you read them.

Haven't heard of the .ecryptfs folder getting that big, I think it's usually just small config files, but maybe it could've got set as the ".private" folder and contained your actual files? That wouldn't be very good.